# Regex for getting filename

Tags: regex

I have string like /sdcard/filename.pdf

Can any one get me the regex to get the "filename" string from the whole path.

Thanks in adv :)

Comment: It's possible that your programming language has specific functions to parse paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[^\/]+$
```

tested [online here on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/x3SMVF5VE6)

The assumption is that your string is only the path.

`$` matches the end of the string
`[^\/]` will match anything except `/`
`+` means match the preceding character (`[^\/]`) at least once

So this will match anything after the last `/` in the string to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything after the last /, you could do this

```
String fileName = pathString.substring(pathString.lastIndexOf("/"),pathString.length());
```

where pathString is the string with the pathname in. (Obviously that will fail if lastIndexOf returns null, so you'll need a bit of error checking.)

A pattern like `/([^\/]+)$/` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression is very simple, here it is:

```
/[\w-_]+/([\w-_]+)\.pdf
```

The brackets are around your 'filename' part, therefore you can thus extract it from the whole path. You find it in the first matching group, group(1) after group(0).

If you would have filepaths of arbitrary folder depth, e.g. /home/myhome/pdf-store/filename.pdf, you would use:

```
(/[\w-_]+)*/([\w-_]+)\.pdf
```

Then you would evaluate the second group for the file name, since the first group denotes the folder path then. I.e. you have it in group(2) then.

Comment: I am sure `\w-_` is not doing what you expect it to do. Put the `-` at the beginning or the end (`[-\w]`) of the character class, if you don't want to escape it, otherwise it defines a range of characters. And `_` is already included in `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/[^/]+/([^\.]+)\..+"
```

Filename is in first backreference.